# bash .profile export statements with spaces in path

Tags: macos, bash, path, spaces, .profile

In my bash `.profile`, I have a series of `export` statements assigning names to commonly used directories.  Some of these directories have spaces in the `path` and are causing problems, because of the way bash treats the spaces.
I know I can use quotes at the bash prompt to solve this problem:

```
cd "$mydir"
```

I am looking for a better way: can I change the export statements themselves within the `.profile` script to do this more tidily, and avoid the need for the quotation marks at the prompt?  I have tried escaping the spaces with backslashes, ticks, multiple quotation marks, everything .... but no success.

I am using "Terminal.app" on OS X 10.9

Comment: You should *always* quote variables in [tag:bash].

Comment: You could switch to `zsh`, which by default does not perform word-splitting on unquoted parameter expansions. `bash` provides no such option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing you can do in the `export` command to fix this. This is just how `bash` expands variables. If the variable is not in quotes, it performs word splitting and wildcard expansion on the result.